# Unicode encode error in python 2.7 for Google Cloud project in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, python-unicode

I have an API in Python, there are no errors if it runs in Mac, only happens with Windows 10, I am using Python 2.7.
I would not like to modify it since the project is working well on PROD and in mac locally but I would like to make it work on my Windows machine.
The error comes from other libraries not from my code, the project is working well except in Windows.

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2689: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal   if item == nloc: E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2695: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal   elif item
== bdir and self.precedence == EGG_DIST: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from bootstrapping import bootstrapping   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 39, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\config.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\client.py", line 52, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 56, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _pycrypto_crypt   File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 17, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 78, in <module>   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 7, in <module>   File "e:\temp\easy_install-38xi7l\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__ UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported. Convert your code to Python 3.

Comment: Find the type of the comparables and see if you are comparing the same type. For example, type(item) , type(nloc)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Unicode strings and bytestrings when checking for equality, which you can confirm by printing `type(comparable 1)` with `type(comparable 2)`  where comparable 1, comparable 2 are the ones you are comparing. This error occurs in Python 2.X when comparing a Unicode string to a byte string. Python 2.X attempts to implicitly convert the byte string to Unicode string using the default ascii codec. If that fails, due to the byte string containing non-ASCII bytes, that warning occurs.

There are 3 approaches by which you can try solving the issue :

1. Decode your text data as early as possible, and only compare Unicode
   objects. So decoding as UTF-8 first would resolve the warning.

You can set UTF-8 on Windows by running:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
Or, create an environment variable with the name 'PYTHONIOENCODING' and value 'UTF-8'
Or, $env:PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-8' with Powershell
```

2. Convert your code to Python 3 as suggested by John Hanley. Python
   3.X reduces the confusion by not allowing non-ASCII characters in a Unicode string literal.
3. You can also change your non-ASCII characters to ASCII characters,
   that way Python 2.X will not fail when trying to convert byte
   strings to Unicode using ascii codec.